# Dictionary of Objects returns incorrect values

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a program that is parsing a plain text database file and creating associations so I can export attachments from the system.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> AttachementsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> BacklogLookupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, BacklogItem> BacklogItemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, BacklogItem>();
        BacklogItem CurrentBacklogItem = new BacklogItem();
        Dictionary<string, Product> ProductDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Product>();
        Product CurrentProduct = new Product();
        string StoryScrumId = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Loading Data From ScrumWorks Database");
        //You need access to this server to run this locally. 
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\\dxScrum01v\ScrumWorksPro\scrumworks\data\hypersonic\scrumworks.script");

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Object Dictionaries");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT"))
            {
                AttachementsDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], line.Split('\'', '\'')[1]);
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEM_ATTACHMENT"))
            {
                if (!BacklogLookupDictionary.ContainsKey(line.Split('(', ',')[1])) 
                {
                    BacklogLookupDictionary.Add(line.Split(',', ')')[1], line.Split('(', ',')[1]);

                }
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEMEJB VALUES"))//-324048562862518297
            {
                    CurrentBacklogItem.ProductScrumId = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[7];
                    CurrentBacklogItem.StoryTitle = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[12];
                    string test = line.Split('(', ',')[1];
                    BacklogItemDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], CurrentBacklogItem);
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO PRODUCTEJB VALUES"))
            {
                CurrentProduct.ProductName = line.Split('\'', '\'')[1].Replace(@"'", string.Empty);
                CurrentProduct.StoryPrefix = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[4].Replace(@"'", string.Empty);

                ProductDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], CurrentProduct);
            }
        }
```

Above is the code to create dictionaries that I use to deal with the associated relationships in the SQL database.

When it runs it appears as the BacklogItemDictionary is populating correctly:

Each backlog item being added to the dictionary is unique:

[image]

[image]

However once the foreach loop ends every value changes to the same incorrect one:

[image]

Every BacklogItem object is the same as above for every key. What am I doing to make the dictonary behave this way? How do I fix it?

Comment: Should be : line.Split(new char[] {',', ')'})[1],

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of creating one instance of `BacklogItem` before the loop which you then reuse later you should create the `BacklogItem` in the loop. Otherwise you are only changing the properties of the single instance on every iteration, actually the last line wins.

So instead of:

```
BacklogItem CurrentBacklogItem = new BacklogItem();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    .... (changes properties everytime and adds the same instance to the dictionary)
}
```

this...

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    BacklogItem CurrentBacklogItem = new BacklogItem();
    .... (initializes this object and adds it to the dictionary)
}
```